# how to convert this java pkcs7gen data signing method to javascript?

Tags: rsa, sha1, private-key, sign, pkcs#7

I am confused with how to convert this java code to javascript this is for signing data. i am confused with what this bouncycastle and i havent found any replacement for this code in javascript nodejs.

It is working fine in java but this process of creating this is to sign my data and the pass it to 3rd party API but my system is in javascript but they have this method of signing the data which i am not able to find the replacement.

```
package pkcs7gen;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CollectionCertStoreParameters;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Pkcs7gen {


    final String SIGNATUREALGO = "SHA1withRSA";

    byte[] signPkcs7(final byte[] content, final CMSSignedDataGenerator generator) throws Exception {

        CMSTypedData cmsdata = new CMSProcessableByteArray(content);
        CMSSignedData signeddata = generator.generate(cmsdata, true);
        return signeddata.getEncoded();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String data = getSignature(args[0]);
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public static String getSignature (String content) throws Exception{

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("./keystore.jks");
        try {
            char[] password= "password".toCharArray();
            keystore.load(input, password);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {


        Enumeration e = keystore.aliases();
        String alias = "";

        if(e!=null)
        {
            while (e.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String  n = (String)e.nextElement();
                if (keystore.isKeyEntry(n))
                {
                    alias = n;
                }
            }
        }
        PrivateKey privateKey=(PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());

        X509Certificate myPubCert=(X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        byte[] dataToSign=content.getBytes();
        CMSSignedDataGenerator sgen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider ());
        sgen.addSigner(privateKey, myPubCert,CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);
        Certificate[] certChain =keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        ArrayList certList = new ArrayList();
        CertStore certs = null;
        for (int i=0; i < certChain.length; i++)
            certList.add(certChain[i]);
        sgen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList), "BC"));
        CMSSignedData csd = sgen.generate(new CMSProcessableByteArray(dataToSign),true, "BC");
        byte[] signedData = csd.getEncoded();
        byte[] signedData64 = Base64.encode(signedData);
        return new String(signedData64);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Pkcs#7 is not supported in javascript so you would need a third party library. This kind of question is off-topic in Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks and i have one more question can you suggest me the alternative for this bouncycastle in javascript.

Comment: Try PKI.js or forge